# "Error parsing query: missing parameter" InfluxDB Python API query while using parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, influxdb, influxdb-python

I have a `UDP InfluxDB` connection:

```
client = InfluxDBClient(host='localhost', database='adatabase', use_udp=True, udp_port=1234)
```

Then, I have the following function:

```
    def getData(self, measurement, field="*", tag="", timeStart=0, timeEnd=0):
    parameters = {"selectedMeasurement": measurement,
                  "selectedField": field}
    print(parameters)
    result = self.client.query('SELECT LAST($selectedField) FROM $selectedMeasurement;', params=parameters)
    print(list(result.get_points()))
    return list(result.get_points())
```

But I get the following error:

```
influxdb.exceptions.InfluxDBClientError: 400: {"error":"error parsing query: missing parameter: selectedField"}
```

I don't understand where the problem is. Also tried with `bind_params`. I use hardcoded fields and measurements, the code works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Influxdb allows to use bind_params ($variable) in the WHERE statement, not in SELECT.

[Influxdb Docs - Bind Parameter](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/tools/api/#bind-parameters)